# Non-integer input skips the rest of the project while only printing instead of asking for remaining values

Tags: c

I have this project where i need to ask the user for an input for 2 arrays (10 and 5 sizes),
When the user doesn't input a correct input (i ask for integer) the program runs all the way to the end, including loops, while only printing output and not asking for the remaining, even when starting a new loop, here is the project, hope you could help me!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

#define B_ARRAY 10
#define S_ARRAY 5

void inputIntArray(int array[], int);
void outputIntArray(int array[], int);
int checkError();

int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
int b_array[B_ARRAY], s_array[S_ARRAY];

int main(){
    // Printing the header
    printf("\n**************\n");
    printf("* Exercise 3 *\n");
    printf("**************\n\n");
    printf("Please fill in the numbers in the 'Big' array (%d) :\n",B_ARRAY);
    printf("(Entering a non-integer will skip to the next step)\n\n");
    inputIntArray(b_array,B_ARRAY);
    printf("\nYour 'Big' array is:\n");
    outputIntArray(b_array,B_ARRAY);
    printf("\nPlease fill in the numbers in the 'Small' array (%d) :\n",S_ARRAY);
    printf("(Entering a non-integer will skip to the next step)\n\n");
    inputIntArray(s_array,S_ARRAY);
    printf("\nYour 'Small' array is:\n");
    outputIntArray(s_array,S_ARRAY);
}

void inputIntArray(int array[], int size){
    int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
    j = size;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("* Enter number #%d out of %d: ",(i+1),j);
        if(scanf("%d",&k) != 1){
            i = j;
        }
        array[i] = k;
    }
}

void outputIntArray(int array[], int size){
    j = size;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I believe you asked a very similar question to this.  If `scanf` fails, that is, it doesn't read an `int` in your case, it leaves all the garbage in the `stdin` buffer.  You have to clear this buffer and then attempt to get proper data again...

Comment: I did, but now what i don't understand is how come the failure in the first run of the inputIntArray() function causes the second run (5 lines below) to fail as well..

Comment: The garbage that is left in the `stdin` buffer is used again and again, unless it is purged...

Comment: Thanks a lot, i added a 'fflush(stdin);' at the bottom and now it will just fill the remaining cells with 0's.